# jax-rs 2.0 and Glassfish 4 unable to @consume JSON into Pojo

Tags: json, glassfish, jax-rs, netbeans-7, java-ee-7

I'm trying to create a plain sample that will consume a json message and inject it in the pojo object.

I'm using the Netbeans dev build with JavaEE7 support and the latest Glassfish 4 promoted build.

When I call the Post method with a json message, I obtain a stackstrace in the log.  At this point, I don't see if I'm doing something wrong.  I was expecting that to work fine in jax-rs 2.

Help will be appreciated.

here the stacktrace and the source code.

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "name" (Class com.demo.User), not marked as ignorable
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@d03ff; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: com.demo.User["name"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:181)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:72)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:134)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:828)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:833)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:245)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.get(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractHttpContextValueFactory.provide(AbstractHttpContextValueFactory.java:66)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:121)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:136)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

User.java

```
package com.demo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {

    public String name;
    public String lastname;

}
```

HelloResource.java

```
package com.demo;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println(HelloResource.class + " post construct");
    } 

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello(){
        return "hello : ";
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    public void sayHello(String message){
        System.out.println("Say Hello : " + message);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void helloJson(User user){
        System.out.println("helloJson user : " + user);
    }
}
```

NewJerseyClient.java

```
package com.demo;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

/**
 * Jersey REST client generated for REST resource:HelloResource [hello]<br>
 * USAGE:
 * <pre>
 *        NewJerseyClient client = new NewJerseyClient();
 *        Object response = client.XXX(...);
 *        // do whatever with response
 *        client.close();
 * </pre>
 *
 * @author sdionne1
 */
public class NewJerseyClient {
    private WebResource webResource;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/resources";

    public NewJerseyClient() {
        com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
        client = Client.create(config);
        webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI).path("hello");
    }

    public void helloJson(Object requestEntity) throws UniformInterfaceException {
        webResource.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(requestEntity);
    }

    public String getHello() throws UniformInterfaceException {
        WebResource resource = webResource;
        return resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
    }

    public void sayHello(Object requestEntity) throws UniformInterfaceException {
        webResource.type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).post(requestEntity);
    }

    public void close() {
        client.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        NewJerseyClient client = new NewJerseyClient();

        User user = new User();
        user.name="name1";
        user.lastname="lastname2";

        client.helloJson(user);

        client.close();
    }
}
```

I open a Jira Issue to keep trace of that, if someone else had the same issue.

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20515

Comment: I think the issues is with jackson not honoring the XmlAccessType.FIELD annotation. Try making the User class attributes private and providing getters and setters for them.

Answer (score 0):

With JAX-RS 2.0, use the standard JAX-RS Client API, not the Jersey Client API. So, something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();

    User user = new User();
    user.name="name1";
    user.lastname="lastname2";

    javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget myResource = client.target("http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/resources");
    myResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(user);

    client.close();
}
```

I'm not sure why the Jersey Client API didn't work in this case.

For more information, see [The Java EE 7 Tutorial chapter on the Client API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client.htm#BABEIGIH)