# Jax-RS error 500 without exception when try to return JSON

Tags: java, json, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm trying to make a findAll on an Entity having 2 OneToMany relations. When I try the GET on the API, the server print an error 500, with no more indication.
I think the problem comes from the JSON format, vecause when I try in XML, it works.
These 2 cases seem to have the same problem, but the solutions don't work for me :

[Glassfish JAX-RS JSON Mapping Simple Example Internal Server Error 500 No Logs Produced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561479/glassfish-jax-rs-json-mapping-simple-example-internal-server-error-500-no-logs-p)

[JAXB on JAX-RS - JPA Entity with relations returns no JSON HTTP 500 no error on logs (Glassfish)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520665/jaxb-on-jax-rs-jpa-entity-with-relations-returns-no-json-http-500-no-error-on)

The Entity :

```
/**
 * Disruptive
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "disruptive")
@XmlRootElement
public class Disruptive implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "disruptive_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "disruptive_id_seq", sequenceName = "disruptive_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id_disruptive")
    protected Integer idDisruptive;
    private String name;
    private String content;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_initial_situation", referencedColumnName = "id_initial_situation")
    protected InitialSituation initialSituation;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "disruptive") //,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true
    protected List<Event> events;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "disruptive")
    protected List<FinalSituation> finalSituations;

    public Disruptive() {

    }

    public Disruptive(InitialSituation initialSituation) {
        this.setInitialSituation(initialSituation);
    }

    public Integer getIdDisruptive() {
        return idDisruptive;
    }

    public void setIdDisruptive(Integer idDisruptive) {
        this.idDisruptive = idDisruptive;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }    

    public InitialSituation getInitialSituation() {
        return initialSituation;
    }

    public void setInitialSituation(InitialSituation initialSituation) {
        this.initialSituation = initialSituation;
    }

    public List<FinalSituation> getFinalSituations() {
        return finalSituations;
    }

    public void setFinalSituations(List<FinalSituation> finalSituations) {
        this.finalSituations = finalSituations;
    }

    public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public void setEvents(List<Event> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.idDisruptive);
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.content);
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.initialSituation);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Disruptive other = (Disruptive) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.content, other.content)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.idDisruptive, other.idDisruptive)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.initialSituation, other.initialSituation)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The WebService :

```
/**
 * DisruptiveFacadeREST
 */
@Stateless
@Path("disruptive")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class DisruptiveFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Disruptive> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "StoryGeneratorPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public DisruptiveFacadeREST() {
        super(Disruptive.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    public void create(Disruptive entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Disruptive entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Disruptive find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    public List<Disruptive> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("random")
    public Disruptive findRandom(@QueryParam("idInitialSituation") Integer idInitialSituation) {
        System.out.println(idInitialSituation);
        Query query;
        query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT dis FROM Disruptive dis JOIN dis.initialSituation insi WHERE insi.idInitialSituation = :idInitialSituation");
        query.setParameter("idInitialSituation", idInitialSituation);
        List<Disruptive> list= query.getResultList();
        Disruptive dis = null;
        if (!list.isEmpty()){
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            dis = (Disruptive) list.get(0);
        }
        return dis;
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

I use a Glassfish Server and JAX-RS for the services.

Comment: Try to [register a generic ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758691/2587435) to see if you can get a stack trace that way. The exception is probably being swallowed up.

Comment: I don't understand, where can I register the Exception ?

Comment: You don't register the exception. You implement an ExceptionMapper to catch exceptions and do something with it. Copy and paste that DebugMapper and register it with your app

Comment: How do I register I with my app ? I never did that.

Comment: Do you have a class that extends `Application`?

Comment: Yes, is that in the RestResourceClasses() ? By : resources.add(DebugMapper.class);

Comment: Yea, you can do that.

Comment: And so my DisruptiveFacadeREST must implement the DebugMapper too ?

Comment: No. Read more about it [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6352)

Comment: Ok now I catched the exception. Thank you, sorry that was my first time with Jax-RS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved (cfr comments under my question)

So I applied this solution :
[How can I get the stack trace when 500 server error happens in Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757856/how-can-i-get-the-stack-trace-when-500-server-error-happens-in-jersey/45758691#45758691)

So I could see the stack trace :

```
GRAVE:   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:959)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:711)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1692)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25037] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A cycle is detected in the object graph.  This will cause an infinite loop: Test -> be.isl.prj.story.entity.Event@1a1a69fc -> Test]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:957)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25037] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A cycle is detected in the object graph.  This will cause an infinite loop: Test -> be.isl.prj.story.entity.Event@1a1a69fc -> Test
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.objectCycleDetected(XMLMarshalException.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLM
GRAVE:   arshaller.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshalStreamOrWriter(XMLMarshaller.java:1126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:496)
    ... 54 more
```

And I resolved the problem putting the @XmlTransient that I forgot, in the getter of my OneToMany Relation (in Disruptive Entity).