# GlassFish Internal server error without logging when sending JSON

Tags: xml, json, jpa, glassfish, jax-rs

I am modelling, in a JPA framework, the situation of a user selling multiple articles to other users. I have three entities: `User`, `Article` and `Order`. They have the following relationships:

- `User` has @OneToMany relationships with `Order` and `Article`, annotated @XmlTransient.
- `Article` has a @ManyToOne relationship with `User`
- `Order` has @ManyToOne relationships with `User` and `Article`

Everything works right and I can succesfully persist these entities in my database. The problem is when I want to retrieve them from the server. The server sends me without problems objects of type `User` and `Article`, however it fails with an "Internal Server Error" when trying to send an object of type `Order` (which is completely well formed before being sent).

I'm using GlassFish 4, implementing REST web services with JAX. There is no logging for these errors so I don't know where to start to look for a solution! I guess it might be a history of circular relations but I don't really see how it can be fixed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to implement an `ExceptionMapper` that will handle all exceptions, and log them for you.  Then using the logs you can troubleshoot why this is occurring.

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this will help in my case. There are no exceptions inside my REST methods, everything works well up to the "return" statement (I checked this by logging intermediate values). The problem happens somewhere after, in the translation to JSON. That's why I was more interested in the consistency of the relationship structure of my entities.

Comment: Right, that's why I was saying to add an exception mapper.  There is an exception that's causing the 500 error.  I'm guessing it's a lazy initialization exception.  Glassfish probably doesn't print this by default, but if you had an exception mapper you could print it yourself.

Comment: I did it, using [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasyExceptionHandlingWithExceptionMapper?_sscc=t) implementation, but still 500 Error with no additional info...

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40897559/1751640)